# How to convert an XML string to a dictionary?

Tags: python, xml, json, dictionary, xml-deserialization

I have a program that reads an XML document from a socket. I have the XML document stored in a string which I would like to convert directly to a Python dictionary, the same way it is done in Django's `simplejson` library.

Take as an example:

```
str ="<?xml version="1.0" ?><person><name>john</name><age>20</age></person"
dic_xml = convert_to_dic(str)
```

Then `dic_xml` would look like `{'person' : { 'name' : 'john', 'age' : 20 } }`

Comment: str has a few syntax errors. try:str ='<?xml version="1.0" ?><person><name>john</name><age>20</age></person>'

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This is a great module that someone created. I've used it several times. 
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410469-xml-as-dictionary/

Here is the code from the website just in case the link goes bad.

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ElementTree

class XmlListConfig(list):
    def __init__(self, aList):
        for element in aList:
            if element:
                # treat like dict
                if len(element) == 1 or element[0].tag != element[1].tag:
                    self.append(XmlDictConfig(element))
                # treat like list
                elif element[0].tag == element[1].tag:
                    self.append(XmlListConfig(element))
            elif element.text:
                text = element.text.strip()
                if text:
                    self.append(text)


class XmlDictConfig(dict):
    '''
    Example usage:

    >>> tree = ElementTree.parse('your_file.xml')
    >>> root = tree.getroot()
    >>> xmldict = XmlDictConfig(root)

    Or, if you want to use an XML string:

    >>> root = ElementTree.XML(xml_string)
    >>> xmldict = XmlDictConfig(root)

    And then use xmldict for what it is... a dict.
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent_element):
        if parent_element.items():
            self.update(dict(parent_element.items()))
        for element in parent_element:
            if element:
                # treat like dict - we assume that if the first two tags
                # in a series are different, then they are all different.
                if len(element) == 1 or element[0].tag != element[1].tag:
                    aDict = XmlDictConfig(element)
                # treat like list - we assume that if the first two tags
                # in a series are the same, then the rest are the same.
                else:
                    # here, we put the list in dictionary; the key is the
                    # tag name the list elements all share in common, and
                    # the value is the list itself 
                    aDict = {element[0].tag: XmlListConfig(element)}
                # if the tag has attributes, add those to the dict
                if element.items():
                    aDict.update(dict(element.items()))
                self.update({element.tag: aDict})
            # this assumes that if you've got an attribute in a tag,
            # you won't be having any text. This may or may not be a 
            # good idea -- time will tell. It works for the way we are
            # currently doing XML configuration files...
            elif element.items():
                self.update({element.tag: dict(element.items())})
            # finally, if there are no child tags and no attributes, extract
            # the text
            else:
                self.update({element.tag: element.text})
```

Example usage:

```
tree = ElementTree.parse('your_file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
xmldict = XmlDictConfig(root)
```

//Or, if you want to use an XML string:

```
root = ElementTree.XML(xml_string)
xmldict = XmlDictConfig(root)
```

Comment: U can use 'xmltodict' alternatively

Comment: I tried this and it's much faster than xmltodict. For parsing an 80MB xml file it took 7s, with xmltodict it took 90s

Comment: Confirmed... I have not tested this against every edge case but for my rather uncomplicated XML strings, this is pretty fast (about 8 times faster than the `xmltodict` library). Disadvantage is that you have to host it yourself within your project.

Comment: it seems that this code can't deal with array as following:<root>
  <e />
  <e>text</e>
  <e name="value" />
  <e name="value">text</e>
  <e> <a>text</a> <b>text</b> </e>
  <e> <a>text</a> <a>text</a> </e>
  <e> text <a>text</a> </e>
</root>

Comment: Hi there, this works perfect, will add just a snippet for those who can't find `cElementTree`, just change first line to:

`from xml.etree import cElementTree as ElementTree`

Comment: If you have duplicate sub-tags with different attributes, you lose the attributes. For example, I have multiple `<Project name="xyz">` tags, where every `name` is different; this method drops the `name` attribute, making it impossible to distinguish the `Project`'s from each other.

Comment: Down-voting since there are better answers posted below, particularly in handling multiple tags with the same name.

Comment: on a sidenote, if you don't *need* to use Python and are just trying to import the XML as a structured object for manipulation, I found that it was much easier to just use R for this as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17198658/5359531) and [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_xml_files.htm). If you just run `library("XML"); result <- xmlParse(file = "file.xml"); xml_data <- xmlToList(result)` you will import your XML as a nested list. Multiple tags with the same name are fine & tag attributes become an extra list item.

Comment: I used xmltodict but gives the error " parser.Parse(xml_input, True) ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0", I have:                  import xmltodict def handle_artist(_, artist): print(artist['person']) return True xmltodict.parse('activity.xml',item_depth=2, item_callback=handle_artist) . do you know how to fix this error?

Comment: I tried it using python 3. The result was wrong for my XML :  empty list. I successfully used dictify (Erik Aronesty's solution below).

Answer (score 397):

[xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) (full disclosure: I wrote it) does exactly that:

```
xmltodict.parse("""
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<person>
  <name>john</name>
  <age>20</age>
</person>""")
# {u'person': {u'age': u'20', u'name': u'john'}}
```

Comment: also, for future googlenauts - I was able to use this in App Engine, which I had been lead to believe didn't play nicely with most xml libraries in Python.

Comment: Thanks it works well. But why is there always the "u" before string ? How to vanish it ?

Comment: The u is just indicating it's stored unicode string.  It doesn't affect the value of the string in any way.

Comment: Nice. Is there a reverse (dict to xml) function or module?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check for a certain key without exception??
if a key doesnt exist, this OrdererdDict put error.

Comment: Nice. And yes, @ypercube, there is a xmldict.unparse() function for the reverse.

Comment: This might be obvious to some, not to others but anybody writing SOAP definitions, it's helpful to use this xmltodict module with pprint (pretty print).  Just `from pprint import pprint` then `pprint(xmltodict.parse('''your XML'''))`

Comment: You might want to add `import xmltodict` so taht one can copy-paste it.

Comment: when I try to run `xmltodict.parse("file.xml")` I get `xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0`, any ideas what is going on?

Comment: @user5359531 I think the `parse` expects a string (or stream), not a filename

Comment: This is excellent. I'm at a loss to express how little I like XML. I wish that I had found this years ago (instead of ETree, XPATH, and that awful mess). 

As an aside which may help others, I didn't realize that one cannot pprint.pprint() an OrderedDict (this is the result of xmltodict.parse()).   I used json.loads(json.dumps("my-XML-string-object")) to get pprint.pprint() to work.

Again, THANK YOU!

Comment: In some complex cases, it does not traverse the whole XML. My case was XML reply from Uniprot --but xmlschema worked though.  So _caveat emptor_.

Comment: Just a heads up, `xmltodict` and I think most solutions in this page do not parse external entities.

Comment: Great. This also works on `QFile` objects using `PyQt5`

Comment: Thank you very much, your module changes my life. Finally I will not have to deal anymore with XML and ElementTree

Comment: Error: `xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: XML or text declaration not at start of entity`
It works when I remove the line return before the xml tag `<?xml`

Comment: @btt, same error here: Copying your code I get `XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 2, column 0`. Your Solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474741/error-error-parsing-xml-xml-or-text-declaration-not-at-start-of-entity) - Lesson learned: **do not** copy that much

Comment: Is this module still active in 2022? 90 issues including security ones on GitHub, no updates in about 2 years or so...

Comment: If you want it as a plain dictionary instead of an OrderedDict, just type cast it 
`dict(xmltodict.parse(...)`

Answer (score 67):

The following XML-to-Python-dict snippet parses entities as well as attributes following [this XML-to-JSON "specification"](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html). It is the most general solution handling all cases of XML.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def etree_to_dict(t):
    d = {t.tag: {} if t.attrib else None}
    children = list(t)
    if children:
        dd = defaultdict(list)
        for dc in map(etree_to_dict, children):
            for k, v in dc.items():
                dd[k].append(v)
        d = {t.tag: {k:v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in dd.items()}}
    if t.attrib:
        d[t.tag].update(('@' + k, v) for k, v in t.attrib.items())
    if t.text:
        text = t.text.strip()
        if children or t.attrib:
            if text:
              d[t.tag]['#text'] = text
        else:
            d[t.tag] = text
    return d
```

It is used:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
e = ET.XML('''
<root>
  <e />
  <e>text</e>
  <e name="value" />
  <e name="value">text</e>
  <e> <a>text</a> <b>text</b> </e>
  <e> <a>text</a> <a>text</a> </e>
  <e> text <a>text</a> </e>
</root>
''')

from pprint import pprint
pprint(etree_to_dict(e))
```

The output of this example (as per above-linked "specification") should be:

```
{'root': {'e': [None,
                'text',
                {'@name': 'value'},
                {'#text': 'text', '@name': 'value'},
                {'a': 'text', 'b': 'text'},
                {'a': ['text', 'text']},
                {'#text': 'text', 'a': 'text'}]}}
```

Not necessarily pretty, but it is unambiguous, and simpler XML inputs result in simpler JSON. :)

---

### Update

If you want to do the **reverse**, emit an **XML string from a JSON/dict**, you can use:

```
try:
  basestring
except NameError:  # python3
  basestring = str

def dict_to_etree(d):
    def _to_etree(d, root):
        if not d:
            pass
        elif isinstance(d, basestring):
            root.text = d
        elif isinstance(d, dict):
            for k,v in d.items():
                assert isinstance(k, basestring)
                if k.startswith('#'):
                    assert k == '#text' and isinstance(v, basestring)
                    root.text = v
                elif k.startswith('@'):
                    assert isinstance(v, basestring)
                    root.set(k[1:], v)
                elif isinstance(v, list):
                    for e in v:
                        _to_etree(e, ET.SubElement(root, k))
                else:
                    _to_etree(v, ET.SubElement(root, k))
        else:
            raise TypeError('invalid type: ' + str(type(d)))
    assert isinstance(d, dict) and len(d) == 1
    tag, body = next(iter(d.items()))
    node = ET.Element(tag)
    _to_etree(body, node)
    return ET.tostring(node)

pprint(dict_to_etree(d))
```

Comment: Thx for this code!
Additional info: if you use python 2.5 you can't use dictionary comprehension, so you have to change the line

`d = {t.tag: {k:v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in dd.iteritems()}}`

 to

`d = { t.tag: dict( (k, v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v) for k, v in dd.iteritems() ) }`

Comment: I have tested nearly 10 snippets / python modules / etc. for that.
This one is the best I have found. According to my tests, it is :
1) much faster than https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict (based on XML SAX api)       2) better than https://github.com/mcspring/XML2Dict which has some little issues when several children have same names     3) better than http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410469-xml-as-dictionary/  which had small issues as well    and more important :    4) much shorter code than all the previous ones!
   Thanks @K3---rnc

Comment: This is, by far, the most comprehensive answer, and it works on > 2.6, and its fairly flexible.  my only issue is that text can change where it resides depending on whether there's an attribute or not).   i posted an even smaller and more rigid solution as well.

Comment: If you need to get an ordered dict from an XML file, please, you can use this same example with few modifications (see my response below):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148119/how-to-convert-an-xml-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python/#32842402

Comment: This is also pretty nifty and fast when used with `cElementTree` or `lxml.etree`. Note that when using Python 3, all `.iteritems()` have to be changed to `.items()` (same behaviour but the keyword changed from Python 2 to 3).

Comment: Beware: high memory usage

Comment: The answer that actually works perfectly!

Answer (score 46):

This lightweight version, while not configurable, is pretty easy to tailor as needed, and works in old pythons.  Also it is rigid - meaning the results are the same regardless of the existence of attributes.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from copy import copy

def dictify(r,root=True):
    if root:
        return {r.tag : dictify(r, False)}
    d=copy(r.attrib)
    if r.text:
        d["_text"]=r.text
    for x in r.findall("./*"):
        if x.tag not in d:
            d[x.tag]=[]
        d[x.tag].append(dictify(x,False))
    return d
```

So:

```
root = ET.fromstring("<erik><a x='1'>v</a><a y='2'>w</a></erik>")

dictify(root)
```

Results in:

```
{'erik': {'a': [{'x': '1', '_text': 'v'}, {'y': '2', '_text': 'w'}]}}
```

Comment: I like this solution.  Simple and does not require external libs.

Comment: I also like this answer since it's all in front of me (no external links). Cheers!

Comment: I also like it. It gives good results for complex XML, which is not the case for class XmlListConfig above.

Answer (score 8):

Disclaimer:
This modified XML parser was inspired by [Adam Clark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24926806/1440565) 
The original XML parser works for most of simple cases. However, it didn't work for some complicated XML files. I debugged the code line by line and finally fixed some issues. If you find some bugs, please let me know. I am glad to fix it.

```
class XmlDictConfig(dict):  
    '''   
    Note: need to add a root into if no exising    
    Example usage:
    >>> tree = ElementTree.parse('your_file.xml')
    >>> root = tree.getroot()
    >>> xmldict = XmlDictConfig(root)
    Or, if you want to use an XML string:
    >>> root = ElementTree.XML(xml_string)
    >>> xmldict = XmlDictConfig(root)
    And then use xmldict for what it is... a dict.
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent_element):
        if parent_element.items():
            self.updateShim( dict(parent_element.items()) )
        for element in parent_element:
            if len(element):
                aDict = XmlDictConfig(element)
            #   if element.items():
            #   aDict.updateShim(dict(element.items()))
                self.updateShim({element.tag: aDict})
            elif element.items():    # items() is specialy for attribtes
                elementattrib= element.items()
                if element.text:           
                    elementattrib.append((element.tag,element.text ))     # add tag:text if there exist
                self.updateShim({element.tag: dict(elementattrib)})
            else:
                self.updateShim({element.tag: element.text})

    def updateShim (self, aDict ):
        for key in aDict.keys():   # keys() includes tag and attributes
            if key in self:
                value = self.pop(key)
                if type(value) is not list:
                    listOfDicts = []
                    listOfDicts.append(value)
                    listOfDicts.append(aDict[key])
                    self.update({key: listOfDicts})
                else:
                    value.append(aDict[key])
                    self.update({key: value})
            else:
                self.update({key:aDict[key]})  # it was self.update(aDict)
```

Answer (score 6):

The most recent versions of the PicklingTools libraries (1.3.0 and 1.3.1) support tools for converting from XML to a Python dict.

The download is available here:  [PicklingTools 1.3.1](http://www.picklingtools.com/downloads)

There is quite a bit of documentation for the converters [here](http://www.picklingtools.com/html/xmldoc.html): the documentation describes in detail all of the decisions and issues that will arise when converting between XML and Python dictionaries (there are a number of edge cases: attributes, lists, anonymous lists, anonymous dicts, eval, etc. that most converters don't handle).  In general, though,
the converters are easy to use.  If an 'example.xml' contains:

```
<top>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2.2</b>
  <c>three</c>
</top>
```

Then to convert it to a dictionary:

```
>>> from xmlloader import *
>>> example = file('example.xml', 'r')   # A document containing XML
>>> xl = StreamXMLLoader(example, 0)     # 0 = all defaults on operation
>>> result = xl.expect XML()
>>> print result
{'top': {'a': '1', 'c': 'three', 'b': '2.2'}}
```

There are tools for converting in both C++ and Python: the C++ and Python do indentical conversion, but the C++ is about 60x faster

Comment: of course, then if there are 2 a's, this is not a good format.

Comment: Looks interesting, but I have not yet figured out how the PicklingTools are meant to be used - is this just a tarball of source code files from which I have to find the right ones for my job and then copy them into my project? No modules to load or anything simpler?

Comment: I get:  in _peekIntoNextNWSChar
    c = self.is_.read(1)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 6):

You can do this quite easily with lxml. First install it:

```
[sudo] pip install lxml
```

Here is a recursive function I wrote that does the heavy lifting for you:

```
from lxml import objectify as xml_objectify


def xml_to_dict(xml_str):
    """ Convert xml to dict, using lxml v3.4.2 xml processing library """
    def xml_to_dict_recursion(xml_object):
        dict_object = xml_object.__dict__
        if not dict_object:
            return xml_object
        for key, value in dict_object.items():
            dict_object[key] = xml_to_dict_recursion(value)
        return dict_object
    return xml_to_dict_recursion(xml_objectify.fromstring(xml_str))

xml_string = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><NewOrderResp>
<IndustryType>Test</IndustryType><SomeData><SomeNestedData1>1234</SomeNestedData1>
<SomeNestedData2>3455</SomeNestedData2></SomeData></NewOrderResp></Response>"""

print xml_to_dict(xml_string)
```

The below variant preserves the parent key / element:

```
def xml_to_dict(xml_str):
    """ Convert xml to dict, using lxml v3.4.2 xml processing library, see http://lxml.de/ """
    def xml_to_dict_recursion(xml_object):
        dict_object = xml_object.__dict__
        if not dict_object:  # if empty dict returned
            return xml_object
        for key, value in dict_object.items():
            dict_object[key] = xml_to_dict_recursion(value)
        return dict_object
    xml_obj = objectify.fromstring(xml_str)
    return {xml_obj.tag: xml_to_dict_recursion(xml_obj)}
```

If you want to only return a subtree and convert it to dict, you can use *Element.find()* to get the subtree and then convert it:

```
xml_obj.find('.//')  # lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement instance
```

See the lxml docs [here](http://lxml.de/). I hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a simple recursive function to do the job:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
root = ElementTree.XML(xml_to_convert)

def xml_to_dict_recursive(root):

    if len(root.getchildren()) == 0:
        return {root.tag:root.text}
    else:
        return {root.tag:list(map(xml_to_dict_recursive, root.getchildren()))}
```

Comment: By far the simplest solution!

Answer (score 3):

```
def xml_to_dict(node):
    u''' 
    @param node:lxml_node
    @return: dict 
    '''

    return {'tag': node.tag, 'text': node.text, 'attrib': node.attrib, 'children': {child.tag: xml_to_dict(child) for child in node}}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410469-xml-as-dictionary/ works well, but if there are multiple elements that are the same at a given place in the hierarchy it just overrides them.

I added a shim between that looks to see if the element already exists before self.update().  If so, pops the existing entry and creates a lists out of the existing and the new.  Any subsequent duplicates are added to the list.

Not sure if this can be handled more gracefully, but it works:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

class XmlDictConfig(dict):
    def __init__(self, parent_element):
        if parent_element.items():
            self.updateShim(dict(parent_element.items()))
        for element in parent_element:
            if len(element):
                aDict = XmlDictConfig(element)
                if element.items():
                    aDict.updateShim(dict(element.items()))
                self.updateShim({element.tag: aDict})
            elif element.items():
                self.updateShim({element.tag: dict(element.items())})
            else:
                self.updateShim({element.tag: element.text.strip()})

    def updateShim (self, aDict ):
        for key in aDict.keys():
            if key in self:
                value = self.pop(key)
                if type(value) is not list:
                    listOfDicts = []
                    listOfDicts.append(value)
                    listOfDicts.append(aDict[key])
                    self.update({key: listOfDicts})

                else:
                    value.append(aDict[key])
                    self.update({key: value})
            else:
                self.update(aDict)
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative (builds a lists for the same tags in hierarchy):

```py
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ElementTree

def xml_to_dict(xml, result):
    for child in xml:
        if len(child) == 0:
            result[child.tag] = child.text
        else:
            if child.tag in result:
                if not isinstance(result[child.tag], list):
                    result[child.tag] = [result[child.tag]]
                result[child.tag].append(xml_to_dict(child, {}))
            else:
                result[child.tag] = xml_to_dict(child, {})
    return result

xmlTree = ElementTree.parse('my_file.xml')
xmlRoot = xmlTree.getroot()
dictRoot = xml_to_dict(xmlRoot, {})
result = {xmlRoot.tag: dictRoot}
```

Answer (score 2):

@dibrovsd: Solution will not work if the xml have more than one tag with same name

On your line of thought, I have modified the code a bit and written it for general node instead of root:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def xml2dict(node):
    d, count = defaultdict(list), 1
    for i in node:
        d[i.tag + "_" + str(count)]['text'] = i.findtext('.')[0]
        d[i.tag + "_" + str(count)]['attrib'] = i.attrib # attrib gives the list
        d[i.tag + "_" + str(count)]['children'] = xml2dict(i) # it gives dict
     return d
```

Answer (score 2):

From @K3---rnc [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148119/how-to-convert-an-xml-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python#10077069) (the best for me) I've added a small modifications to get an OrderedDict from an XML text (some times order matters):

```
def etree_to_ordereddict(t):
d = OrderedDict()
d[t.tag] = OrderedDict() if t.attrib else None
children = list(t)
if children:
    dd = OrderedDict()
    for dc in map(etree_to_ordereddict, children):
        for k, v in dc.iteritems():
            if k not in dd:
                dd[k] = list()
            dd[k].append(v)
    d = OrderedDict()
    d[t.tag] = OrderedDict()
    for k, v in dd.iteritems():
        if len(v) == 1:
            d[t.tag][k] = v[0]
        else:
            d[t.tag][k] = v
if t.attrib:
    d[t.tag].update(('@' + k, v) for k, v in t.attrib.iteritems())
if t.text:
    text = t.text.strip()
    if children or t.attrib:
        if text:
            d[t.tag]['#text'] = text
    else:
        d[t.tag] = text
return d
```

Following @K3---rnc example, you can use it:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
e = ET.XML('''
<root>
  <e />
  <e>text</e>
  <e name="value" />
  <e name="value">text</e>
  <e> <a>text</a> <b>text</b> </e>
  <e> <a>text</a> <a>text</a> </e>
  <e> text <a>text</a> </e>
</root>
''')

from pprint import pprint
pprint(etree_to_ordereddict(e))
```

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to an [ActiveState solution](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/116539/) - and the code in case it disappears again.

```
==================================================
xmlreader.py:
==================================================
from xml.dom.minidom import parse


class NotTextNodeError:
    pass


def getTextFromNode(node):
    """
    scans through all children of node and gathers the
    text. if node has non-text child-nodes, then
    NotTextNodeError is raised.
    """
    t = ""
    for n in node.childNodes:
    if n.nodeType == n.TEXT_NODE:
        t += n.nodeValue
    else:
        raise NotTextNodeError
    return t


def nodeToDic(node):
    """
    nodeToDic() scans through the children of node and makes a
    dictionary from the content.
    three cases are differentiated:
    - if the node contains no other nodes, it is a text-node
    and {nodeName:text} is merged into the dictionary.
    - if the node has the attribute "method" set to "true",
    then it's children will be appended to a list and this
    list is merged to the dictionary in the form: {nodeName:list}.
    - else, nodeToDic() will call itself recursively on
    the nodes children (merging {nodeName:nodeToDic()} to
    the dictionary).
    """
    dic = {} 
    for n in node.childNodes:
    if n.nodeType != n.ELEMENT_NODE:
        continue
    if n.getAttribute("multiple") == "true":
        # node with multiple children:
        # put them in a list
        l = []
        for c in n.childNodes:
            if c.nodeType != n.ELEMENT_NODE:
            continue
        l.append(nodeToDic(c))
            dic.update({n.nodeName:l})
        continue

    try:
        text = getTextFromNode(n)
    except NotTextNodeError:
            # 'normal' node
            dic.update({n.nodeName:nodeToDic(n)})
            continue

        # text node
        dic.update({n.nodeName:text})
    continue
    return dic


def readConfig(filename):
    dom = parse(filename)
    return nodeToDic(dom)





def test():
    dic = readConfig("sample.xml")

    print dic["Config"]["Name"]
    print
    for item in dic["Config"]["Items"]:
    print "Item's Name:", item["Name"]
    print "Item's Value:", item["Value"]

test()



==================================================
sample.xml:
==================================================
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Config>
    <Name>My Config File</Name>

    <Items multiple="true">
    <Item>
        <Name>First Item</Name>
        <Value>Value 1</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Name>Second Item</Name>
        <Value>Value 2</Value>
    </Item>
    </Items>

</Config>



==================================================
output:
==================================================
My Config File

Item's Name: First Item
Item's Value: Value 1
Item's Name: Second Item
Item's Value: Value 2
```

Comment: Yes it is. Have reproduced the code here in case it goes again.

Answer (score 1):

Updated method posted by [firelion.cis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1418315/firelion-cis) (since getchildren is deprecated):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
root = ElementTree.XML(xml_to_convert)

def xml_to_dict_recursive(root):

    if len(list(root)) == 0:
        return {root.tag:root.text}
    else:
        return {root.tag:list(map(xml_to_dict_recursive, list(root)))}
```

Answer (score 0):

At one point I had to parse and write XML that only consisted of elements without attributes so a 1:1 mapping from XML to dict was possible easily. This is what I came up with in case someone else also doesnt need attributes:

```py
def xmltodict(element):
    if not isinstance(element, ElementTree.Element):
        raise ValueError("must pass xml.etree.ElementTree.Element object")

    def xmltodict_handler(parent_element):
        result = dict()
        for element in parent_element:
            if len(element):
                obj = xmltodict_handler(element)
            else:
                obj = element.text

            if result.get(element.tag):
                if hasattr(result[element.tag], "append"):
                    result[element.tag].append(obj)
                else:
                    result[element.tag] = [result[element.tag], obj]
            else:
                result[element.tag] = obj
        return result

    return {element.tag: xmltodict_handler(element)}


def dicttoxml(element):
    if not isinstance(element, dict):
        raise ValueError("must pass dict type")
    if len(element) != 1:
        raise ValueError("dict must have exactly one root key")

    def dicttoxml_handler(result, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for e in value:
                dicttoxml_handler(result, key, e)
        elif isinstance(value, basestring):
            elem = ElementTree.Element(key)
            elem.text = value
            result.append(elem)
        elif isinstance(value, int) or isinstance(value, float):
            elem = ElementTree.Element(key)
            elem.text = str(value)
            result.append(elem)
        elif value is None:
            result.append(ElementTree.Element(key))
        else:
            res = ElementTree.Element(key)
            for k, v in value.items():
                dicttoxml_handler(res, k, v)
            result.append(res)

    result = ElementTree.Element(element.keys()[0])
    for key, value in element[element.keys()[0]].items():
        dicttoxml_handler(result, key, value)
    return result

def xmlfiletodict(filename):
    return xmltodict(ElementTree.parse(filename).getroot())

def dicttoxmlfile(element, filename):
    ElementTree.ElementTree(dicttoxml(element)).write(filename)

def xmlstringtodict(xmlstring):
    return xmltodict(ElementTree.fromstring(xmlstring).getroot())

def dicttoxmlstring(element):
    return ElementTree.tostring(dicttoxml(element))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified one of the answers to my taste and to work with multiple values with the same tag for example consider the following xml code saved in XML.xml file

```
     <A>
        <B>
            <BB>inAB</BB>
            <C>
                <D>
                    <E>
                        inABCDE
                    </E>
                    <E>value2</E>
                    <E>value3</E>
                </D>
                <inCout-ofD>123</inCout-ofD>
            </C>
        </B>
        <B>abc</B>
        <F>F</F>
    </A>
```

and in python

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET




class XMLToDictionary(dict):
    def __init__(self, parentElement):
        self.parentElement = parentElement
        for child in list(parentElement):
            child.text = child.text if (child.text != None) else  ' '
            if len(child) == 0:
                self.update(self._addToDict(key= child.tag, value = child.text.strip(), dict = self))
            else:
                innerChild = XMLToDictionary(parentElement=child)
                self.update(self._addToDict(key=innerChild.parentElement.tag, value=innerChild, dict=self))

    def getDict(self):
        return {self.parentElement.tag: self}

    class _addToDict(dict):
        def __init__(self, key, value, dict):
            if not key in dict:
                self.update({key: value})
            else:
                identical = dict[key] if type(dict[key]) == list else [dict[key]]
                self.update({key: identical + [value]})


tree = ET.parse('./XML.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
parseredDict = XMLToDictionary(root).getDict()
print(parseredDict)
```

the output is

```
{'A': {'B': [{'BB': 'inAB', 'C': {'D': {'E': ['inABCDE', 'value2', 'value3']}, 'inCout-ofD': '123'}}, 'abc'], 'F': 'F'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse(xml_filepath).getroot()

def parse_xml(node):
    ans = {}
    for child in node:
        if len(child) == 0:
            ans[child.tag] = child.text
        elif child.tag not in ans:
            ans[child.tag] = parse_xml(child)
        elif not isinstance(ans[child.tag], list):
            ans[child.tag] = [ans[child.tag]]
            ans[child.tag].append(parse_xml(child))
        else:
            ans[child.tag].append(parse_xml(child))
    return ans
```

it merges same field into list and squeezes fields containing one child.

Answer (score -1):

Slightly improved version of [fvg's fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65639426) of [firelion.cis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72582919). The function is simple, and works for **simple XML**, and avoids the innermost singleton dictionaries. **NOT** suitable for complex XML with tags, or if the XML have more than one tag with same name.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

# Replace xml_to_convert below
root = ElementTree.XML(xml_to_convert)

def xml_to_dict(root):
    if len(root):
        return {root.tag:{k:v for d in map(xml_to_dict, root)
                              for k,v in d.items() }}
    else:
        return {root.tag:root.text}
```

Sample XML:

```
<student>
    <FirstName>SMITH</FirstName>
    <LastName>JAMES</LastName>
    <fees>
        <Amount>2400</Amount>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
    </fees>
</student>
```

Output *(formatted)*:

```
{'student': {'FirstName': 'SMITH',
             'LastName': 'JAMES',
             'fees': {'Amount': '2400', 
                      'Currency': 'USD'}
            }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I have a recursive method to get a dictionary from a lxml element

```
    def recursive_dict(element):
        return (element.tag.split('}')[1],
                dict(map(recursive_dict, element.getchildren()),
                     **element.attrib))
```

Comment: This solution is missing some code, such as import and set up. I got the message 'str' object has no attribute 'tag'