# Is there a way to turn XML into dictionary and lists?

Tags: python, xml, string, list

```
<things>
    <fruit>apple</fruit>
    <hardware>mouse</hardware>
...
</things>
```

Turn it into:

```
{'things':[{'fruit':'apple'}, {'hardware':'mouse'}]}
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate.  All of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+xml+dictionary. Specifically, this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148119/how-to-convert-a-xml-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python

Comment: if you know how to use xpath well, you can process xml as if it is a list, or a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a nice recipe for that here:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/570085/

another good one is here:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/522991/