# Error:(6) error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity

Tags: android, xml, android-menu

My android project gives this error while I'm trying to build it.I found several solutions which tell me to remove whitespace initially. But unfortunately, I don't have any whitespace. So can you please let me know why my error occurred and possible solution?

My XML is here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_allplace"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_all_places"
            android:title="@string/nav_title_all_place" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_categories"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_categories"
            android:title="@string/nav_title_categories" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_map"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_map"
            android:title="@string/nav_title_map" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ar"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_ar_camera"
            android:title="@string/nav_ar_map" />

    </group>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="none">
        <item android:title="@string/nav_title_my_activities">
            <menu>
                <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/nav_review"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_rate_review"
                        android:title="@string/nav_title_rates_and_reviews" />
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_collections"
                        android:title="@string/nav_title_gallery" />
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_cancel"
                        android:title="@string/nav_title_sign_out" />
                </group>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="none">
        <item android:title="@string/setting_test">
            <menu>
                <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/nav_about"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
                        android:title="@string/str_about" />
                </group>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>


</menu>
```

Comment: refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474741/error-error-parsing-xml-xml-or-text-declaration-not-at-start-of-entity

Comment: @MohammadAli Why? The problem in that question are the garbage letters at the very start of the document, which is not the problem here.

Comment: becoz in this link same problem like this question so

Comment: ?????????????????/

Comment: I will phrase it differently. The answer below seems much more plausibly helpful than your link. The problem in your link is solved by getting rid of the garbage letters at the very start of the document. I consider the answer below (removing what looks like correct XML from later in the document) to plausibly be what will actually help OP. Same error message is not the same as same problem, even less the same as same solution.

Comment: @MohammadAli Actually 2 of the 3 letters I first considered "garbage" are by accident ("X" for marking the point and the reverse quote probably for bad markdown) but the first one (the space) is the actual problem. So while I was somewhat wrong my statement happens to remain true. Also, OPs explicit statement that solutions by removing white space did not help (OP, my compliment for now obvious research effort, by the way) render your comment noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the extra

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`