# To draw rounded rectangle in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable, shapes

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618402/how-to-draw-rounded-rectangle-in-android-ui) and the solution was this code :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

This code doesn't work on my PC (no rounded corners). And you ? There has been changes ?

**EDIT 1:**
I have an error when I build the project : AAPT: error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity. (finally corrected : stupid mistake from me)

**EDIT 2** :
The error is now :
The following classes could not be found:
- corners (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- shape (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- solid (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
Tip: Try to build the project.

XML layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="120dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="120dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="120dp"
            android:topRightRadius="120dp" />

    </shape>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

SOLUTION :

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618402/how-to-draw-rounded-rectangle-in-android-ui)

Comment: please share the xml layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you couldn't see the rounded rectangle as the radii are small so that they might not be noticed, try to set larger values for the four corners

Here is `120dp` radii

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="120dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="120dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="120dp"
        android:topRightRadius="120dp" />

</shape>
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

> EDIT 2 : The error is now : The following classes could not be found: - corners (Fix Build Path, Edit XML) - shape (Fix Build Path, Edit XML) - solid (Fix Build Path, Edit XML) Tip: Try to build the project.

You can't use drawable tags into xml layout directly like `<shape>` or `layer-list`, instead you can refer to drawable resource with some layout view attributes like `android:background` as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thx. I have already tried this and doesn't work. But I have an error when I build the project : AAPT: error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity.

Comment: @jujuf1 that could have more than one [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474741/error-error-parsing-xml-xml-or-text-declaration-not-at-start-of-entity), but I don't think the provided drawable can do something with that .. can you provide your xml and if you have some java/kotlin behavior to share

Comment: I have an error into the xml layout. Error is :
The following classes could not be found:
- corners (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- shape (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- solid (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
Tip: Try to build the project.

Comment: Thx for your reply but if you refer to the stackoverflow question link that i have post, the developpers manage to does work that. I don't undestand