# Using colander for xml deserialization

Tags: python, pylons, pyramid, colander

How should [colander](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/?awesome) be used for xml deserialization? Docs say that it can even be used for xml deserialization and validation, but I didn't find any good examples for that in docs or on the web!

If anyone has used colander for xml deserialization can you just put a snippet here on its usage? It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at `colander` as a tool for 'deserialization/validation *from a python dictionary*'. A dict in Python can be formed from any structured data format, I guess.

In one of my projects I validate POST (`webob.multidict`) data and a JSON file and use the same lines of code:

```
recipe_schema = RecipeSchema()
try:
    appstruct = recipe_schema.deserialize(cstruct)
...
```

`cstruct` is always a dict, as mentioned above - sometimes made of processed `Multidict`, sometimes made of `json.load(json_data)`.

So, [transform XML to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148119/how-to-convert-a-xml-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python) first and then validate the dict with `colander`.