# From XML to template file- attributes starting with @

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, xml-parsing

I'm stuck with sending xml to template engine in gae.
I'm using a suggested xmltodict here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10199714/27186

The problem is at attribute level:

```
{{xml.response.parameters.parameter.0}}
```

returns

```
OrderedDict([(u'@type', u'item'), (u'@kind', u'page..'), ..etc.
```

i tried do access `type` with

```
{{xml.response.parameters.parameter.0.type}}
{{xml.response.parameters.parameter.0.attrib.type}}
{{xml.response.parameters.parameter.0.attrib['@type']}}
```

and those don't work. The last one throws 
`TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '['@type']'`

How should i access those attributes?

Comment: have you tried ['@type']? what are the @ doing there?

Comment: @theAlse i think i made wrong impression- i'm accessing the `type` from the template engine of GAE. The ['@type'] would work in python code.