# Python - Scraping website data - formatting printed results

Tags: python, xml, regex, rss

I have been experimenting on python 2.7.3 to extract data from an RSS feed so I can output it to the python shell.

I found a video on you tube on the subject and copied the code from their tutorial.

The code works and extracts the data i need but the output of the data is set out wrong

the code is as follows:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import re
import cookielib
from cookielib import CookieJar
import time

cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')]


def main():
    try:
        page = 'http://thewebsite/feed/rs/rss.xml'
        sourceCode = opener.open(page).read()

        try:
            titles = re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)</title>',sourceCode)
            desc = re.findall(r'<description>(.*?)</description>',sourceCode)
            links = re.findall(r'<link>(.*?)</link>',sourceCode)
            pub = re.findall(r'<pubDate>(.*?)</pubDate>',sourceCode)


            for title in (titles):
                print title

            for description in desc:
                print description

            for link in links:
                print link

            for pubDate in pub:
                print pubDate

        except Exception, e:
            print str(e)


    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)

main()
```

The problem is that when I run the code I see a long list if titles, then a list of descriptions, then a list of links, then a list of dates.

like this:

```
The Title
The Title
The Title
the description
the description
the description
the link
the link
the link
the date
the date
the date
```

What I really want is the output showing

```
The Title
the description
the link
the date

The Title
the description
the link
the date

The Title
the description
the link
the date
```

Can anyone help with correcting the output?

I really want to just grab headlines from the RSS feed and output them to the shell.

The purpose is to use this on a raspberry pi instead of using the web browser.

Any help much appreciated.

**UPDATE*****

Also the RSS feed I am parsing from has extra tags at the beginning which include elements called title and link. Any way these can be excluded???

Code starts with this:

****DONT WANT THIS. HAS TAGS I DONT WANT TO USE

```
    <RSS>    
      <channel> 
         <title>DBE News</title>  
        <link>http://www.BDE.co.uk/news//#sa-ns_mchannel=rss&amp;ns_source=PublicRSS20-            sa</link>  
         <description>The latest stories from the BDE News web site.     </description>  
         <language>en-gb</language>  
        <lastBuildDate>Fri, 17 Jan 2014 22:11:54 GMT</lastBuildDate>  
        <copyright>Copyright: DBE, see   http://DBE.com for terms and conditions of reuse.   </copyright>  
       <image> 
          <url>http://news.DBE.co.uk/nol/shared/img/DBE.gif</url>  
          <title>DBE News</title>  
           <link>http://www.DBE.co.uk/news/uk/#sa-ns_mchannel=rss&amp;ns_source=PublicRSS20- sa</link>  
          <width>120</width>  
          <height>60</height> 
         </image>  
         <ttl>15</ttl>  
        <atom:link href="http://feeds.DBE.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml" rel=" self"       type="application/rss+xml"/>
```

****DONT WANT THIS. HAS TAGS I DONT WANT TO USE

****NORMAL FEED STARTS HERE. WANT ALL THE INFO HERE

```
    <item> 
      <title>Stackover flow is cool</title>  
      <description>Get the answers here.</description>  
      <link>http://www.DBE.co.uk/news/Stsck# sa-  ns_mchannel=rss&amp;ns_source=PublicRSS20-sa</link>  
      <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.DBE.co.uk/news/uStack</guid>  
      <pubDate>Fri, 17 Jan 2014 21:38:05 GMT</pubDate>  
      <media:thumbnail width="66" height="49"     url="http://news.DBEimg.co.uk/media/images/72364000/jpg/_72364484_mikaeel.jpg"/>  
      <media:thumbnail width="144" height="81"   url="http://news.DBEimg.co.uk/media/images/72364000/jpg/_72364485_mikaeel.jpg"/> 
    </item>  
   <item>
```

The extra tags cause a 'list index out of range' error.

Comment: You could parse the xml as data and do something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148119/how-to-convert-an-xml-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python

Comment: I wrote some code to do this at first but the results returned no data. This code worked on another XML file i had downloaded using python.

Comment: [It's not a good idea to use regular expressions to parse xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196624/hide-html-code-temporarily-and-display-them-later/21196742#21196742); you'd be best to work out a proper decoding like that and implement a dict/enumerator or do what @jramirez suggests afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your 4 for loops with this:

```
for i in range(len(titles)):
    print titles[i]
    print desc[i]
    print links[i]
    print pub[i]
    print ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. Note that this will `only` work if there always the same amount of elements in all four lists. If say there are six elements in `titles` and three in `desc` you will get an `IndexError` exception.

```
        for i,title in enumerate(titles):
            print title
            print desc[i]
            print links[i]
            print pub[i]
            print ""
```