# How to convert large xml file into csv using Python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I want to convert a very large XML file into CSV format without hardcoding tagnames.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Without any additional information about the structure of your XML files there is no reasonable answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to parse your XML files. This can be done via [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

Example code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('your_data.xml').getroot()
with open("output.csv", "w") as file:
    for child in root:
        print(child.tag, child.attrib)
        # naive example how you could save to csv line wise
        file.write(child.tag+";"+child.attrib)
```

[There are also solutions to parse your XMLs directly as dictionary.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148119/how-to-convert-an-xml-string-to-a-dictionary)

Then [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) can be used to save the dictionary as CSV.

Comment: root = ET.parse('your_data.xml').getroot()
this fails for very large XML files, as they cannot be loaded into memory