# Parse XML to Table in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse XML to table-like structure in Python.
Imagine XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<base>
  <element1>element 1</element1>
  <element2>element 2</element2>
  <element3>
    <subElement3>subElement 3</subElement3>
  </element3>
</base>
```

I'd like to have result like this:

```
KEY                       | VALUE
base.element1             | "element 1"
base.element2             | "element 2"
base.element3.subElement3 | "subElement 3"
```

I've tried using xml.etree.cElementTree, then functions described here [How to convert an xml string to a dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148119/how-to-convert-an-xml-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python)

Is there any function that can do this? All answers I found are written for particular XML schemes and would need to be edited for each new XML scheme.
For reference, in R it's easy with XML and XML2 packages and xmlToList function.

Comment: So what have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: You might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148119/how-to-convert-an-xml-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried parsing it using xml.etree.cElementTree, then functions described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148119/how-to-convert-an-xml-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python and I'm just wondering whether there is some simple function similar to that one in R. I'm new to Python, don't use it normally and all tutorials that I found were written for a particular XML schema and would require editing for any other. The reason why I don't simply use R is that I believe it could be much faster with Py.

Comment: Please [edit] to give a [mcve] illustrating the specific problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've got the needed outcome using following script.

**XML File**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<base>
  <element1>element 1</element1>
  <element2>element 2</element2>
  <element3>
    <subElement3>subElement 3</subElement3>
  </element3>
</base>
```

**Python code**:

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree

data = "C:/Path/test.xml"

tree = etree.parse(data)

lstKey = []
lstValue = []
for p in tree.iter() :
    lstKey.append(tree.getpath(p).replace("/",".")[1:])
    lstValue.append(p.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({'key' : lstKey, 'value' : lstValue})
df.sort_values('key')
```

**Result**:

[image: Python result]