# XML to DATAFRAME and back to XML in python

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe

I would to convert XML file into pandas dataframe.

Afterwards I would like to convert the dataframe back to exactly the same XML.

**[First step]**: save the XLM file from string:

```
    xml = '''<system>
    <station id="1" type="DeviceName Functional Test">
      <stationId>Functional_Test</stationId>
    </station>
    <software>
      <component version="1.0.0.0" date="01/01/1889">Functional_Test.exe</component>
    </software>
</system>'''
element = ET.XML(xml)
ET.indent(element)
pretty_xml = ET.tostring(element, encoding='unicode')
    
xml_file_name = r"save_xml.xml"
xml_file=open(xml_file_name,"w")
xml_file.write(str(pretty_xml))
xml_file.close()
```

**[Second step]:** read the xml and save it as csv using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_xml(xml_file_name)
df.to_csv("xml_to_csv.csv")
```

[image]

**[Third step]:** convert dataframe back to XML:

```
back_to_xml = df.to_xml(index = False, root_name = "system", xml_declaration = False)
remove_rows = back_to_xml.replace("<row>", "").replace("</row>", "")
print(remove_rows)
```

Unfortunately the output XML is not the same as the input XML.

```
<system>
  
    <id>1.0</id>
    <type>DeviceName Functional Test</type>
    <stationId>Functional_Test</stationId>
    <component/>
  
  
    <id/>
    <type/>
    <stationId/>
    <component>Functional_Test.exe</component>
  
</system>
```

I would much apricate any support and guidance.

Comment: Why not use original xml structure, if you don’t make changes? In pandas you can define the xml attribute in a list,  `attr_cols=[]`, compare pandas [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/2.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xml.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Second step]**: Save XML as DataFrame
Using James code in [How to convert an XML string to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148119/how-to-convert-an-xml-string-to-a-dictionary) XML can be converted to well structured df.

In my case:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class XmlListConfig(list):
    def __init__(self, aList):
        for element in aList:
            if element:
                if len(element) == 1 or element[0].tag != element[1].tag:
                    self.append(XmlDictConfig(element))
                elif element[0].tag == element[1].tag:
                    self.append(XmlListConfig(element))
            elif element.text:
                text = element.text.strip()
                if text:
                    self.append(text)


class XmlDictConfig(dict):
    def __init__(self, parent_element):
        if parent_element.items():
            self.update(dict(parent_element.items()))
        for element in parent_element:
            if element:
                if len(element) == 1 or element[0].tag != element[1].tag:
                    aDict = XmlDictConfig(element)
                else:
                    aDict = {element[0].tag: XmlListConfig(element)}
                if element.items():
                    aDict.update(dict(element.items()))
                    
                self.update({element.tag: aDict})
            elif element.items():
                self.update({element.tag: dict(element.items())})
            else:
                self.update({element.tag: element.text})

path = r"save_xml.xml"
tree = ET.parse(path)
root = tree.getroot()
xml_dict = XmlDictConfig(root)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(xml_dict)
csv_path = rf"{path[:-4]}.csv"
df.to_csv(csv_path)
```

**[Third step]**: using ElementTree structure convert dataframe back to XML:

```
def parse_df_to_xml(csv_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, index_col=0)
    root = ET.Element("system")
    for column in df.columns:
        row  = df[column]
        if column == "station":
            station = ET.SubElement(root, str(column), id = row.id, type = row.type)
            ET.SubElement(station, "stationId").text = row.stationId
        elif column == "software":
            software = ET.SubElement(root, str(column))
            component_dict = eval(row.component)
            ET.SubElement(software, "component", version = component_dict["version"], date = component_dict["date"]).text = "Functional_Test.exe"
    return root

root = parse_df_to_xml(csv_path)

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
ET.indent(tree, space="\t", level=0)
tree.write("df_to_xml.xml")
```