convert XML into xlsx
I'm trying to convert an XML into xlsx using the following code in python:
with open(str(Path.cwd())+'\test.xml', "rb") as f1:
    with open(str(Path.cwd())+'\test.xlsx', "wb") as f2:
        f2.write(f1.read())
        f2.close()
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(str(Path.cwd())+'\test.xlsx')

but I'm getting the following error:
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(str(Path.cwd())+'\test.xlsx')
ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.

is there a way to convert the xml into xlsx file directly?

I hope this question would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78063175/xml-to-dataframe-and-back-to-xml-in-python

Your code had to fail since .xlsx files are in fact zipped containers.

Use pandas to read the xml and than write it to Excel with pandas.

Consider conducting some research on these two fundamentally different data types.

@Parfait Might be a bit disingenuous; XLSX is literally a zip archive of XML files.

Yes, XLSX is an archive of XMLs with other metadata. And OP does not seem to attempt that route but use the zipped up Excel binary format as if it was a text file. My tone may have read wrong but research on these types could guide OP on earnest attempt at solution.
